# configparser parse string as unicode in python2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, unicode

I am parsing a file with ini format using configparser module in python 2. I am using configparser instead of ConfigParser so that code is compataible with python 3.

Problem that with python 2 parsed "value " is coming as unicode string as u'value'.

Please note that with python 3 parsed value is same as python2 if I would use ConfigParser instead.

Is there a way to resolve this?

Sample config file:

```
$ cat test_config
[test]
field = value
```

Python run

```
$ python
Python 2.7.14 (default, Nov  2 2017, 17:39:03)
>>> import configparser
>>> config_name = "test_config"
>>> 
>>> config_parser = configparser.SafeConfigParser()
>>> config_parser.optionxform = str
>>> config_parser.read(config_name)
>>> config = {}
>>> mode = 'test'
>>> for item_tuple in config_parser.items(mode):
...     config[item_tuple[0]] = item_tuple[1]
... 
>>> print(config['field'])
value
>>> config['field']
u'value'
>>>
```

Comment: Why do you care if the output is in unicode? The output in Python3 is also implicitly unicode.

Comment: If it is unicode then either I have to explictly do str(output) or other parts of my code will break (which are not under my control)

Comment: Do you assume they will break, or do they actually break? Why do you expect that you will have to do `str(output)`? If you get any encoding related issues you should ask about the actual errors you get, not about a workaround that you think fits (XY problem)

Comment: I don't have control on the api I use. This api helps to launch a process and when I am reading config this way, command created using this config doesn't work.

Comment: Also I am trying to understand why python3 doesn't give u'output' put python2 gives u'output' with configparser.

Comment: Because in Python 3 all string literals are implicitly unicode. In Python 2 there are str and unicode types, Python 3 only have str.

Comment: Ok Thanks. So is there a way other than str(output) to handle my use case?